# How to read Hadoop HDFS 64b compressed files from one Hadoop cluster on another Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, compression, hdfs

I have 64 b compressed Hadoop HDFS files(FSImage, edit logs, blk_*.meta files etc) of one Hadoop cluster and I want to read them on my local VM. As an option I'm thinking like:

1. Taking backup of my DataNode, NameNode and SecondaryNameNode
2. Format the DataNode, NameNode and SecondaryNameNode
3. Copy the files into respective location
4. Map the configuration properties
5. Restart the HDFS.

This might be the one of the way. Please help me to figure out if there is any alternative for the above approach. My apologies that i can not share the data.

Comment: AFAIK, you can do I/O regarding data within a cluster from any machine if Hadoop libraries are installed, simpy writting the right URI, something like `hdfs://remote_namenode:port/path/to/the/data`.

Comment: I have files in folder. Also i need to read blk_* & blk_*.meta files